# What's the meaning of 'mapping' in web development?

Tags: asp.net-core, mapping

I'm new to web-development and stumbled across the term **'**mapping**'**. What does it mean and what is it good for?

Extra: What's AutoMapping in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping is very useful in web development.

There are database tables which contain data and some data may be sensitive.

If you work directly in database entities your data are exposed and this is dangerous and unethical so you map these entities in ViewModels or Data-Transfer-Object in which you choose what data to retrieve from database entity.

Imagine having the entity Customer:

```
public Customer {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
  public double Bugdet {get;set;} //sensitive data
  public double AmountSpent {get;set;} //sensitive data
  public string CreditCardNumber{get;set;} //sensitive data
}
```

So you cannot use this entity directly because all data will be exposed.

Instead you must create a Data-Transfer-Object (DTO) like this so you get only information needed:

```
public CustomerDto {
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public string LastName {get;set;}
    }
```

Automapping is a process of mapping entity to DTO automatically handled by any library.

Heavily used is Automapper which need a little of configuration.

Read more about AutoMapper [here](https://automapper.org/)